# Maintaining the state of a listing while navigating back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React application that displays a list of users and allows navigation to their details. My intention is that, when the user presses the back button in the browser, the list of users should not be reloaded upon returning to it.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom'

function UsersList () {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setUsers(data))      
  }, [])

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

function UserDetail () {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${location.pathname.split('/')[2]}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setUser(data))
  }, [location])

  if (!user) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <p>{user.description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/users' element={<UsersList />} />
        <Route path='/users/:id' element={<UserDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

And my index.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

What am I missing? Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app navigates from `"/users"` to `"/users/:id"` the `UsersList` component unmounts and any local state it had is lost. Life the `users` state up higher in the ReactTree such that the component hosting it remains mounted while navigating between the user routes.

Example:

```
function App () {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(setUsers);  
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/users'
          element={<UsersList users={users} />} // <-- pass users as props
        />
        <Route path='/users/:id' element={<UserDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
function UsersList ({ users }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

If you don't want to move the state and logic *all* the way up to `App` then an alternative is to create a user routes layout component that holds the state and exposes it out via the `Outlet` component's context provider.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const UsersLayout = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(setUsers);  
  }, []);

  return <Outlet context={{ users }} />;
};

export default UsersLayout;
```

```
function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<UsersLayout />}>
          <Route path='/users' element={<UsersList users={users} />} />
          <Route path='/users/:id' element={<UserDetail />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
import { Link, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

function UsersList () {
  const { users } = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <Link to={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```